# VectorDrawableCompat Exception after Androidx migration

Tags: android, build.gradle, androidx, android-vectordrawable

Exception while open SplashActivity (Error on super.onCreate(savedInstanceState))

I can't fix it tried so many solutions. 
Please help me.

I am also giving all the details of error checkout.

```
   --------- beginning of crash
        2019-03-26 16:03:12.695 8791-8791/com.xxxxx.xxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: com.xxxxx.xxxxxx, PID: 8791
            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/vectordrawable/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat;
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.isVectorDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:513)
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.checkVectorDrawableSetup(ResourceManagerInternal.java:505)
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:137)
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411)
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
                at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:358)
                at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:80)
                at com.smartisystems.smartbtcard.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:25)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3061)
                at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:114)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6716)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxxxx.xxxxxx-izn3J5Pqq9HwraGe_0OlbQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxxxx.xxxxxx-izn3J5Pqq9HwraGe_0OlbQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.isVectorDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:513) 
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.checkVectorDrawableSetup(ResourceManagerInternal.java:505) 
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:137) 
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411) 
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86) 
                at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:358) 
                at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:80) 
                at com.smartisystems.smartbtcard.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:25) 
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3061) 
                at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:114) 
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6716) 
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Please help me out for this problem.

I'am also adding gradle file details below. all the possible solution is tried but still problem is there.

Build.gradle(:app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    flavorDimensions "default"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        xxxxxxx {
            applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 5
            versionName "1.4"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            //  buildConfigField is for Constants. We have to pass three params as below
            // (DATA-TYPE, FIELD-NAME, VALUE)
            buildConfigField("String", "ORG_ID", "\"XXXXX\"")
        }
        xxxxx{
           applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 5
            versionName "1.4"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            //  buildConfigField is for Constants. We have to pass three params as below
            // (DATA-TYPE, FIELD-NAME, VALUE)
            buildConfigField("String", "ORG_ID", "\"XXXX\"")
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkDependencies true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.matecode:Snacky:1.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.SubhrajyotiSen:library:1.1.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'si.inova:neatle:0.9.8'
    //implementation 'mobi.inthepocket.android:ibeaconscanner:2.0.0'
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
}
```

Comment: android {
    defaultConfig{
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

Comment: @LukasNovicky already added in build.gradle(:app) but issue is still there.

Comment: you need to replace support dependencies with androidx dependency in build.gradle.

Comment: replace `com.android.support:support-vector-drawable` with `androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0`

Comment: build -> clean project?

Comment: @KaranMer there's `1.0.1` already... and I voted to close this, because there is no `build.gradle`. stack-traces without the code which produces them are insufficient.

Comment: @MartinZeitler  updated with build.gradle code. Please check.

Comment: @MartinZeitler : mistake on my side, I checked only the migration guide, didn't looked for updated version of dependency. thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @LukasNovicky Not worked for me.